# Formatting an ObjectProperty<LocalDateTime> in a TableView column

Tags: java, datetime, javafx, tableview

In this example, I would like for a column in my `TableView` to format from `LocalDateTime` (which is in the source data model) to the format of "yyyy/MM/dd kk:mm" in a `TableColumn`. (Note: For rendering, not editing) Well, I will need to work with Local/ZonedDateTime types in a few data models when displaying in table views.  What is the best way to do this?  (I did not notice an example of this type of capability in the Oracle Table View tutorial).

Edit-add: Or, maybe keeping the values in the data models as `String` (formatted), and converting to `LocalDateTime` for when used in processing records would be best?

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        final ObservableList<Foo> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();
        data.add(new Foo(ldt));
        data.add(new Foo(ldt.plusDays(1)));
        data.add(new Foo(ldt.plusDays(2)));

        TableView<Foo> table = new TableView<Foo>();
        table.setItems(data);

        TableColumn<Foo, LocalDateTime> ldtCol = new TableColumn<Foo, LocalDateTime>("LDT");
        // --- Set cell factory value ---

        table.getColumns().addAll(ldtCol);
        Scene scene = new Scene(table);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    class Foo {
        private final ObjectProperty<LocalDateTime> ldt = 
                new SimpleObjectProperty<LocalDateTime>();

        Foo(LocalDateTime ldt) {
            this.ldt.set(ldt);
        }

        public ObjectProperty<LocalDateTime> ldtProperty() { return ldt; }
        public LocalDateTime getLdt() { return ldt.get(); }
        public void setLdt(LocalDateTime value) { ldt.set(value); }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can have the `TableColumn` as `TableColumn<Foo, LocalDateTime>`: use the `LocalDateTime` property as value and you can define the [`cellFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#setCellFactory-javafx.util.Callback-) for the column to display it:

```
TableColumn<Foo, LocalDateTime> ldtCol = new TableColumn<Foo, LocalDateTime>("LDT");
ldtCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().ldtProperty());
ldtCol.setCellFactory(col -> new TableCell<Foo, LocalDateTime>() {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(LocalDateTime item, boolean empty) {

        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty)
            setText(null);
        else
            setText(String.format(item.format(formatter)));
    }
});
```

---

Alternatively, you can have a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to convert the `LocalDateTime` into a `String`, but i**n this case table sorting will not work** (will use string ordering). Thanks @JFValdes to point that out.

In this case you can use the [`setCellValueFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#setCellValueFactory-javafx.util.Callback-) method of `TableColumn` to display it as a `String` on the `TableView`.

```
private final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm");

...    

TableColumn<Foo, String> ldtCol = new TableColumn<Foo, String>("LDT");
ldtCol.setCellValueFactory(foo -> new SimpleStringProperty(foo.getValue().getLdt().format(formatter)));
```

Comment: Just curious about one thing... With this formatting string, does the hh work the same as kk ? (I had kk, and you have hh)

Comment: Yes, of course. Check the link of `DateTimeFormatter`, there you can see all of the pattern letters you can use. Also there are lots of predefined constants supported.

Comment: You know, I was just tinkering with it, and kk allows for 24:mm time.  But HH does not.  So that seems different.  Btw: Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, just point out that your first case won't sort well because TableView object treats every item as a String, not as a LocalDateTime, so it will be sorted as String.